# Firebase return null instance in Helper class

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

```
class FirebaseHelper {


    companion object {

        private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null

        fun getInstance(): FirebaseAuth? {
            if(mAuth == null ){
                mAuth == FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            }
            return mAuth;
        }

        fun getCurrentUser(): FirebaseUser?{
            return getInstance()?.currentUser
        }
    }
}
```

Here `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` always return null and I don't get why.  If I use it on an activity like

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
```

it return the firebase instance. I don't get what is the difference. I tried to not make the FirebaseHelper.getInstance() method static, but it also didn't work.

Any hints?

Comment: If you use the emulator, try to use a real device.

Comment: I didn't use the emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class FirebaseHelper {

    companion object {

        private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null

        fun getInstance(): FirebaseAuth? {
            if(mAuth == null ){

                // here you should use "=" instead of "=="
                mAuth == FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            }
            return mAuth;
        }

        fun getCurrentUser(): FirebaseUser?{
            return getInstance()?.currentUser
        }
    }
}
```